# Dependent List in Excel

Tags: excel

My question is , in excel when we create a dependent dropdown we write the formula for the other dropdown dependent on the first one. For example if USA is selected in first col the matching City of USA will be pulled and then can be populated in a data validation list.

I know how to write formula to get the items matching criteria. My problem is what if we have multiple dropdowns .

For example we have 100 rows with column A for selecting Countries and then next to each of these we have dropdown for selecting City.

Do I need to write 100 formulas for these dependent dropdowns or there is another way around to achieve this?

Comment: Without VBA you can do something like have data validation tied to a single list but use spreadsheet formulas to populate that single list in different ways, depending on other selections. With VBA, you of course have a lot more flexibility.

Comment: There is a ton of references if you do an internet search. There are several methods shown at Debra Dagleish's Contextures web site which might be applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following,

[image: dependent_list]

The data validation lists in A2:A10 are based on a List with a Source: of,

```
=$AA$2:$AA$5
```

The data validation lists in B2:B10 are based on a List with a Source: of,

```
=INDEX($AB$2:$AE$6, 0, MATCH($A2, $AB$1:$AE$1, 0))
```

<sub>[sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/dependent_data_validation_lists.xlsx)</sub>