# Excel Custom Validation more than one Level

Tags: excel

I have a drop down the Has "B" and "C" and would like to add another validation level. Example if value in Cell A1 is Not one of the states below, then Don't allow the Selection of "A" from the drop down. Thanks

```
AK
AZ
AR
CA
CO
CT
DE
DC
FL
GA
HI
ID
IL
IN
IA
```

Comment: What do you want as output and what have you tried so far?

Comment: What I am trying to do is simple by definition, but I think complicated (at least for me) implementation wise. There is a drop down that the user selects and it is either "A" or "B". IF the Value in Cell A1( also a drop down) is not one of the states mentioned, then the user shouldn't be able to select A from that drop down.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand your question, but I THINK you want to remove items from the dropdown that have already been used in previous cells.

This is possible with a careful setup of a few named ranges that evaluate the data. Outlining the whole technique would be too much for this answer, but you can read a step by step tutorial by Debra Dahlgliesh here:

[Hide used items in dropdown list](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal03.html)

Comment: Maybe the op is talking about cascading dropdowns?

Comment: Yah, could be. A bit of punctuation and editing from the OP would help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to 'Cascading' or 'Dynamic' dropdowns? e.g. if the user was to select a country in their dropdown, in the next dropdown you only want them to see items relevant to that particular country? If so, see [Dependent List in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433241/dependent-list-in-excel/36435446#36435446)