# Show N/A in a cell with data validation based on value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

If D11 (which is a dropdown) shows 'cash' then D13 needs to show N/A - but as D13 is also a dropdown (separate from the one in D11) I'm struggling with how to incorporate the IF function - please can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: You can't have `D13` show `N/A` without VBA, because selecting a value would overwrite your formula, when you use one. You can however limit the selection to `N/A` dependent on the value of `D11`. Look for dependent drop-down on here for that.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/36433622/12634230